# Onclick of thumbnail, change image

Tags: jquery, onclick

I'm trying to implement a small gallery. It's made in Wordpress and all the data comes from advanced custom fields.

This is the HTML I have: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RbY2D/)

I need to make it so that when the user clicks a thumbnail image, it changes the main image. This could be with a data attribute or possibly just overlay the image. It just needs to change the image path.

I had a look through the onClick function but I am not sure how to bind that event to the main feature image and also how to get the stored link of the thumbnail.

The thumbnail images are currently large enough that they can be used as the large image too.

```
$("#target").click(function() {
  alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other ways to accomplish this, one of them is changing the image attribute i.e.

```
$('#imageClick').click(function(){
  $('#mainImage').attr('src','source');           
});
```

[**Demo on fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RbY2D/5/)

Comment: Thanks, I am having a few problems with this solution. I have the script updated with my PHP calls but I'm getting an error. Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function http://pastebin.com/BUvQQxnX

Comment: You should include [jquery script](http://jquery.com/download/)
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>`